# How to iterate data in table from multi dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I currently having trouble in iteration of data to table from multidimension array.

Here is my string.

`str = 'stack%splitoverflow,php%splitcodeigniter'`

My logic here is first, im gonna split the string from `,` delimiter.

Here is the result.

`result_array = ['stack%splitoverflow', 'php%splitcodeigniter']`

Next, I'll gonna split each array value from `%split` delimiter

Now, My question is how im gonna put that value in table like this:

```
| col1             | col2        |
------------------------------
| stack            | overflow    |
| php              | codeigniter |
---------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an example for your question .I splitted your object values and made another object and finally bind obj value to table. Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var result_array = ['stack%splitoverflow', 'php%splitcodeigniter'];
$.makeArray(result_array);

$.each( result_array,function(index,obj){
 var data=obj.replace("%split",",");
 
 var newobj=data.split(",");
    $(".table").append("<tr><td>"+newobj[0]+"</td><td>"+newobj[1]+"</td></tr>")
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="tblContainer">
<table class='table table-bordered'>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to log this as a table, you can use [`console.table()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table):

```js
let str = 'stack%splitoverflow,php%splitcodeigniter';
let separated = str.split(',').map(s=>s.split('%'));

console.table(separated);
```